# Python selecting with (java-enabled?) dropdown selection

Tags: python, html

am new to coding and have been trying to select a dropdown box to select underlying options. Have been able to interact with other drop-down on this page, though this particular one seems different as I've been unable to access/interact with it

I've included a snapshot of the webpage's drop-down box, source codes for the specific drop-down box, and codes that I've already tried and had errors with.

Would appreciate any help/pointers. Am a complete newb to coding (python or HTML!), but know a little about Excel VBA.

website: https://www.firstsentierinvestors.com/sg/en/retail/performance/price-and-performance.html

Tried to paste a picture though it seems I'm too new to do so directly. I'm trying to interact with the "Select Fund" drop-down box on the page. Have tried the following codes:

```
browser.find_element_by_id('strategy').send_keys(fund_strat) #works fine

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="share-class"]').click() 
#this line directly above does not work, including variants below:


browser.find_element_by_xpath('THE BELOW XPATHS').click()
//*[@id="price-performance-form"]/div[3]
//*[@id="price-performance-form"]/div[3]/div
//*[@id="price-performance-form"]/div[3]/div/a
//*[@id="price-performance-form"]/div[3]/div/a/span
//*[@id="share-class"]
//*[@id="share-class"]/option[1]

Also tried using CSS selector
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('a.option-selected').click()
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('a.option-selected').send_keys('NAME OF FUNDS ETC')
```

[Image describing problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aa7L5.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the below line works fine for you then,

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="share-class"]').click() 
#this line directly above does not work, including variants below:
```

You need to wait for the element which is visible on the DOM.
i.e.,css = `<div class="custom-select custom-select-open">`

These days most of the web apps are using AJAX techniques.
So you need to add a wait duration (till the element gets visible on the page or get loaded on the DOM).

So, Try using Selenium Waits(put below code):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XX, 'element')))
```

XX = CSS, XPATH, ID, etc.

Now, If you want to write on the selected text box then just try to send keys on `input` element.

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.editable-select input')
```

for much better selector use parent elements to locate the exact element.

```
CSS = 'div[class$="custom-select custom-select-open"] .editable-select input'
```

If you want to select dropdown options and you know the Values. Try using below CSS.

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('select option[value$="Your Value"]')
```

or

If you don't know the values then please attach whole DOM feed after typing into the text box. I'll try to help you out with the Dropdown selection of item.

Else, there is few more steps are there that you need to workout. Get all elements using inside text.

Note: You can approach the text search of an element using XPATH. Example : `xpath = "//*[contains(text(),'your text')]"`